# sending crtl+c to a node.js spawned childprocess using stdin.write()?

Tags: node.js, stdin, spawn, child-process

In a node script, I have spawned a child process which executes a batch file run.bat , to terminate the program started by the batch-file i need to send ctrl+c combination to the child process , it is required for me to send ctrl+c combination to the program using stdin.write() method.

```
var hmc = require('child_process').spawn('cmd');
hmc.stdin.write('run.bat \n');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is equivalent to sending a `SIGINT` on Windows. Rather than trying to send a keystroke to the process, you can send a signal instead. This can either be done with a child process method or from other processes, provided that you have the process ID of the child:

```
hmc.kill('SIGINT');
// or from another process
process.kill(hmc.pid, 'SIGINT');
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events      Note that Windows does not support sending Signals, but node offers some emulation with process.kill(), and child_process.kill(): - Sending signal 0 can be used to search for the existence of a process - Sending SIGINT, SIGTERM, and SIGKILL cause the unconditional exit of the target process.

Comment: So it wont be a signal in windows. You will just kill the process immediately (not gracefully).

Comment: @garkin's comment is right, the signal is NOT sent, but rather the child process is just unconditionally killed.