# Nodejs: Send Ctrl+C to a child process on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, signals, child-process

Hi I am using child_process.spwan to start a child process running a python script on Windows. The script listens on SIGINT to gracefully exits itself. But Windows does not support signals and all node did was simulating. So `child_process.kill('SIGINT')` on Windows is actually killing the process unconditionally (no graceful exit, python's SIGTERM/SIGINT handler not called). Also writing a `ctrl+c` character to stdin does not work either.

When I look into Python APIs, I got the [CTRL_BREAK_EVENT](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/21025/signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT) and CTRL_C_EVENT that can serve the need. I am wondering if node has equivalent platform-specific APIs like these?

Related posts but not working ones:
[How to send control C node.js and child_processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648654/how-to-send-control-c-node-js-and-child-processes)
[sending crtl+c to a node.js spawned childprocess using stdin.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406887/sending-crtlc-to-a-node-js-spawned-childprocess-using-stdin-write)

Comment: It is said to be impossible here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41976985/2604492

Answer (score 1):

You can use IPC messages to signal to the child that its time to stop and gracefully terminate. The below approach uses [`process.on('message')`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/process.html#process_event_message) to listen for messages from the parent in the child process & [`child_process.send()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback) to send messages from the parent to the child.

The below code has a 1 minute timeout set to exit if the child hangs or is taking to long to finish.

**py-script-wrapper.js**

```
// Handle messages sent from the Parent
process.on('message', (msg) => {
  if (msg.action === 'STOP') {
    // Execute Graceful Termination code
    process.exit(0); // Exit Process with no Errors
  }
});
```

**Parent Process**

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const py = cp.fork('./py-script-wrapper.js');

// On 'SIGINT'
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  // Send a message to the python script
  py.send({ action: 'STOP' }); 

  // Now that the child process has gracefully terminated
  // exit parent process without error
  py.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    process.exit(0);
  });

  // If the child took too long to exit
  // Kill the child, and exit with a failure code
  setTimeout(60000, () => {
    py.kill();
    process.exit(1);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks. This certainly works when the child is a node process. But what if eventually I need to spawn a Python process (e.g., `spawn('python', ['myscript.py']`), which holds some resources (e.g.,  sockets) but does not speak Javascript at all. How can I IPC the python proc in a cross-platform manner?

Answer (score 0):

You could send a 'quit' command via stdin to the Pyhthon process, that worked for me. In Python you need to create a thread which reads from stdin using `input`, once this returns, you set an event flag. In your main application loop you regularly check whether the event has been set and exit the program.

Python application (script.py):

```
import threading
import sys

def quit_watch(event):
    input("Type enter to quit")
    event.set()

def main():
    stop = threading.Event()
    threading.Thread(target=quit_watch, args=[stop]).start()

    while True:
        # do work, regularly check if stop is set
        if stop.wait(1):
            print("Stopping application loop")
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Node.js application:

```
child_process = require('child_process')
child = child_process.spawn('python.exe', ['script.py'])
// check if process is still running
assert(child.kill(0) == true)
// to terminate gracefully, write newline to stdin
child.stdin.write('\n')
// check if process terminated itself
assert(child.kill(0) == false)
```